# Proving $\left(\tan x +\frac{1}{\tan x}\right) \left(\sin x+\cos x\right)=\frac{1}{\cos x}+\frac{1}{\sin x}$

Tags: trigonometry

$$
\left(\tan x +\frac{1}{\tan x}\right) \left(\sin x+\cos x\right)=\frac{1}{\cos x}+\frac{1}{\sin x}
$$

Can someone show me how to solve this identity and also explain the steps?

Comment: You could try expressing everything in terms of sines and cosines, clear fractions, and see what you get.

Comment: I don't think this is true. See [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28tan%5E2+x+%2B+1%2Ftan+x%29+%28+sin+x+%2B+cos+x%29+-+1%2Fsin+x+%2F+cos+x)

Comment: It's false.  Plug in $x=\pi/4$.

Comment: Maybe you want the sum $\frac{1}{\cos x}+\frac{1}{\sin x}$ instead of the product?  Not saying I checked this ..

Comment: Sorry @Doc you are right

Comment: My teacher says we aren't supposed to plug in numbers. we are supposed to use the other method

Comment: how can we do it without plugging in numbers

Comment: And your teacher is right.  I just plugged in a value to prove the "identity" was not an identity.  Note that only _one_ counterexample is needed in that case.

Comment: Well, did you try to follow Gerry's suggestion above?

Comment: Bet you anything you want that your $\tan^2{x}$ term should be $\tan{x}$.

Comment: @doc Yes once again you would be right. I don't know how to edit it due to the coding

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying out on the left hand side you get: $(tan + \frac{1}{tan})\cdot (sin+cos) \\ = (\frac{sin}{cos}+\frac{cos}{sin})\cdot (sin + cos) \\ = \frac{sin^2}{cos}+ cos + sin + \frac{cos^2}{sin} \\ = \frac{sin^2}{cos}+\frac{cos^2}{cos}+\frac{sin^2}{sin}+\frac{cos^2}{sin} \\ = \frac{1}{cos}+\frac{1}{sin}.$

Hence, $(tan + \frac{1}{tan})\cdot (sin+cos) = \frac{1}{cos}+\frac{1}{sin}$. Now just apply these operators to $x$.

Comment: Depriving OP of the joy of working this out on his/her own.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, perhaps... I was feeling generous today.

Comment: I don't follow. The generous thing to do is to let OP work through the answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: In retrospect, I probably should not have answered; will hold off from answering questions of a similar ilk in future.